# Setting up parLapply() for parallel processing

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have a very large dataset (17,000 features in 360 samples), for which i need to calculate some diversity indices. This takes extremely long (3-4 days on a single sample), so i want to go parallel. I have about 50 cpus available, so each cpu should do about 7 samples (columns) sequentially.

I can run this:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(sample.int(1000, 2000*360, TRUE), 2000, 360))
dflist <- as.list(df)

library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores()-1)

clusterExport(cl, "dflist")
results <- parLapply(cl, df.list, function(x) range(x)) #range as a wild card
```

, and this yields the desired output, but i dont know if this really works as i think it works.
So, my question is:
Does this command let each process pick up the next free object in `dflist`, once it has finished its current task?
Or do i have to assign a specific set of objects in `dflist` to each process?

Comment: Please read the documentation for [`?parLapply`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/parallel/versions/3.5.2/topics/clusterApply), specifically where it talks about load balancing. (Hint: you might prefer `parLapplyLB`, since I'm inferring that the increased communication will have negligible effects on your overall calculation time.) Other than that, your code here is about as vanilla as you can get for `parallel` use.

Comment: thank you, i indeed didnt bother to rtfm.